# Question about existence of $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{1}{1+\cot x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I read on a book that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x} \left(1+\frac{1}{1+\cot x}\right)$ does not exist. I tried to find out why, by choosing sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $\cot x_n=0$ and $\cot y_n=1$, $\forall~ n\in\mathbb{N}.$ However, we have the factor $e^{-x}$ as a result the limit goes to $0$ over those two sequences. Any Ideas would be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: you'd have better luck looking at $x\to(n\pi/2)^\pm$ for odd integers $n$.

Comment: An easier method would be to recognize that $\lim_{x \to \infty} cot(x)$ does not exist, hence this limit does not exist.

Comment: @Hersh That's not enough. The limit of $\csc x$ ($e^{-x}(1+1/\csc x)$) doesn't (does) exist.

Comment: @J.G. makes sense. My bad.

Comment: Why do you write $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x} \left(1+\frac{1}{\cot x}\right)$ if you can easily replace it by $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x} \left(1+tg(x)\right)$? :-)

Comment: I make a mistake previously. Is not $\frac{1}{\cot x}$ but $\frac{1}{1+\cot x}$. Sorry I should rewrite the exercise
@J.G.
I suppose I will apply  the same idea

Comment: In that case, approach roots of $\tan x=-1$ from either side.

Comment: @J.G. $x_n=n\pi -\pi/4 - 1/n$

Comment: Replace the $-1/n$ offset with $+\epsilon$, then see what happens for _sufficiently small_ $\epsilon$ of either sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;$ we consider the following function :

$f(x):\left]n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}4,\,n\pi\right[\to\Bbb R\;$ defined as

$f(x)=e^{-x}\left(1+\dfrac1{1+\cot x}\right)\quad$ for all $\;x\in\left]n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}4,\,n\pi\right[.$

The function $\,f(x)\,$ is continuous on $\left]n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}4,\,n\pi\right[,$ moreover

$\lim\limits_{x\to\left(n\pi-\frac{\pi}4\right)^+} f(x)=-\infty\;\;$ and $\;\lim\limits_{x\to n\pi^-}f(x)=e^{-n\pi}>0\;.$

By applying the intermediate value theorem, it follows that there exist $\;a_n,\;b_n\in\left]n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}4,\,n\pi\right[\;$ such that $\;f(a_n)=-1\;$ and $\;f(b_n)=-2\;.$

Consequently, there exist two sequence $\,\big\{a_n\big\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$,$\,\big\{b_n\big\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=+\infty\;\;$ and $\;f(a_n)=-1\;,\;f(b_n)=-2\;,\quad\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,.$

If there existed the limit $\;\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}e^{-x}\left(1+\dfrac1{1+\cot x}\right)=l\;\;,$
it would result that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{-a_n}\left(1+\dfrac1{1+\cot a_n}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\big(\!-1\big)=l\quad$ and

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{-b_n}\left(1+\dfrac1{1+\cot b_n}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\big(\!-2\big)=l\;\;,$ consequently,

$l=-1=-2\;$ which would be a contradiction.

Hence, it does not exist the limit $\;\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}e^{-x}\left(1+\dfrac1{1+\cot x}\right).$